# In 1926 human conception of the universe changed forever

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is it correct to use the word *forever* in the sentence implying that something changed since that moment?

This is the particular sentence I'm struggling with:

> In 1926 human conception of the universe changed forever

(If you find a better option, please tell me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example sentence, "forever" modifies "changed".

If the word "forever" were omitted, it would be likely that subsequent change(s) (after 1926) might undo the change:

> In 1926, the human conception of the universe changed.

With the word "forever", the sentence claims that no subsequent change(s) will ever undo the change.  The sentence implies that the change was especially rare, in two ways:  the use of the word "forever", and the implication that similar changes happen less often than once per year:

> In 1926, the human conception of the universe changed forever.